# How to get transaction details using transaction ID of a paypal transaction in asp.net mvc C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We have integrated paypal payment gateway in our website and transaction is working fine on sandbox account in INR (Not in USD).
But after making a successful payment, paypal redirected to our website, with redirect url and query string append on it like paymentId,token,PayerID
and we also get the Transaction ID from c# code.

Now we need to get the details of that particular transaction (as attached in the image) like name, Buyer,Delivery address, Description,Unit price, Qty, Amount and Invoice ID etc.
How do I get these details in our website for making invoices in Asp.net MVC. Please help.
[image]

Comment: paypal has an API. Have you looked to see if it can return the data you need?

Answer (score 0):

When in your C# code you capture/execute the payment and receive the transaction ID, you are (in that same response) also already receiving transaction details.

The details _*are*_ there. Look for them in the response object you already have.

---

More importantly, it appears you have done two bad things with your integration:

- You've integrated using the old v1/payments API , possibly with the deprecated PayPal-Net-SDK
- You are using redirects instead of an in-context integration

Recommendations to address the above:

- Switch to the newest v2/checkout/orders API, using the Checkout-Net-SDK, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ . You'll need two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction (create order)' and one for 'Capture Transaction (capture order)'
- Do not use any redirects. At all. Instead, keep your website open in the background so the buyer knows what they are paying for and stays within a familiar environment, and open PayPal in that context.  Here is the approval flow to use, paired with the above two routes on your server: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: We are using the latest paypal Rest API SDK. and for transaction ID we are using this code.   `var executedPayment = ExecutePayment(apiContext, payerId, Session[guid] as string);`
` var trId = executedPayment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id;`    private `Payment ExecutePayment(APIContext apiContext, string payerId, string paymentId)
        {
            var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId };
            this.payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };
            return this.payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
        }`

Comment: You are using the deprecated PayPal-Net-SDK.

Comment: We got all details using this SDK except buyer name and buyer email. Above code returns all data. Can you tell me how to get buyer name and email. I don't know which sdk is latest because nuget package is not showing any deprecated message for it. and paypal website is also referring this SDK. I am following this url [ http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/Samples/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx.html ]

Comment: Here is the link to the GitHub repo with the deprecation message plus link to the new repo for the Checkout-NET-SDK therein: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK

Comment: Remember to read both my recommendations above which link to the documentation on what to do with this newer SDK...